# how to try n times then pass the errors while using urllib in lambda function in python?

Tags: python, lambda, try-catch, urllib

I'm trying to convert short urls in a pandas column to actual urls using `urllib` in python 3. 
There might be invalid urls which can't be opened in the browser. In this case, I want to skip them and continue with the rest.

I tried to use `lambda`, but it threw errors like `bad gateway`, `no name found` etc. And the `try-except` will just return nothing if any error happens. 
Also, I tried `for loop`, but it took more than 1 hour.

```
try:
    df['url2'] = df['url'].apply(lambda x: urllib.request.urlopen(x).geturl())
except:
    pass

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    try:
        df['url2'][i]=urllib.request.urlopen(df['url'][i]).geturl()
    except:
        pass
```

Would be good if the scripts can skip errors (re-try if possible) and finish processing 10k rows of urls in less than 1 min.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at https://pypi.org/project/retrying/, it's a Python library to deal with "retries". It's quite easy to integrate in an existing project.

Considering your second wish ("finish processing 10k rows of urls in less than 1 min"), this is probably not feasible, because each attempt needs at least one HTTP request, and 10k requests in less than 1 minute is a bit too optimistic. However, you can probably be a little bit faster by parallelizing the attempts, but that's a different question.

Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue. Put all URLs in a queue, then create workers that will consume these URLs to check if they are valid or not. If no "new URLs" are provided meanwhile you're processing the existing ones, then https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool could be easier to deal with.

Comment: Now I know why it took so long. I chose to deduplicate the urls and save the results for next processing to save some time. Still multiprocessing is worthwhile to look into. Thanks!